# converting a factor column into a date within a dataset in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset which contains a date like this 2.01.2006 00:00 but when I read the file it was converted into a factor. I want to convert it into Date type. I have used these two methods for the conversion but I am getting NAs instead:

1) `mydata$date = as.Date(mydata$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`

2) `mydata$date <- strptime(x = as.character(mydata$date), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`

What is the mistake in these two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your date uses period as a separator, so your format mask should match this:

```
mydata$date <- as.Date(mydata$date, format = "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M")
```

For the sample data you gave:

```
2.01.2006 00:00
```

the following date is output:

```
[1] "2006-02-01"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
mydata$date <- anydate(mydata$date)
```

Using a reproducible example

```
str1 <- "2.01.2006 00:00"
anydate(str1)
#[1] "2006-02-01"
```